# Ruby On Rails Not Creating The View For A Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm definitely very new to Ruby on Rails. I created a new rails folder like this:

Edit: Sorry for the inconvienience, but I did use the `--api` tag.

```
rails new <project-name> -d mysql --api
```

since I use `mysql` instead of `sqlite`. Then, in the tutorial they used a command like this:

```
rails generate controller Welcome index
```

I did the exact same thing, however in the log it shows this:

```
   create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
   route  get 'welcome/index'
```

It didn't seem to create the view. I don't know why it's doing this. After I start the server with `rails server` I can go to the `localhost:3000/welcome/index` but it just takes me back to the home page, and in the log it says `Started GET .... No Content ...` . So it couldn't find the view. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can always create a view manually under `app/views/`. For example, `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` is the view that would be associated with the index action in the welcome controller.

Comment: controller generators don't create views. scaffolds do though.

Comment: @Viktor that's where I checked, however it wasn't there.

Comment: @JoshBrody How do I create scaffolds associated to a view? The same generate command?

Comment: I'm following [this website](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Is it outdated? If so, what tutorial isn't?

Comment: @JoshBrody That's not true, `g controller` should generate views too unless it's an API only project, check [1.3](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

Comment: @Higigig You can create the file yourself. If you're on linux or macOS you can cd into the `views/welcome` folder and just do `touch index.html.erb`

Comment: @JoshBrody You were correct! I was creating an API only project, I switched it to application and it works now.

Comment: If you're looking to learn web development with Ruby on Rails, I would recommend something like [The Odin Project](https://theodinproject.com) . It's completely free and gives you a clear path in learning web development for both (or either) back and front end development :)

Comment: i had a hunch that you were using API-only project based on the get no content ;) happy to hear it's solved.

Comment: Try generating scaffold instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you created an API only project with the `--api` flag, the `rails generate controller Welcome index` command should have created an `index.html.erb` file in the views folder.

You can either delete the `welcome_controller.rb` file and the generated line from the `route.rb` file and run the command again or you can manually create the view with the `touch` command (assuming your OS supports the `touch` command):

```
touch app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
```

or through you favourite text editor or IDE. On a side note, controller names should be plural (`WelcomePagesController` for example).

Comment: Yup, I used the ```--api``` tag. Sorry you had to do more research than you needed, but I got my answer from you. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :)